# SQL не выводит результаты при COUNT(*) = 0

Tags: count, sql

Есть 2 таблицы:  posts и comments, соответственно для каждого поста (pid) может быть несколько комментариев (cid), считаю кол-во комментов и вывожу pid и их. Но почему-то выводит посты только те у кого ,COUNT(cid)>0, добавление условий HAVING не помогло. Что посоветуете?

```
SELECT p.pid,COUNT(*) FROM posts p INNER JOIN comments c ON c.pid= p.pid GROUP BY p.pid
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вместо INNER надо использовать LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: Да стал выводить все строки, но у тех у кого COUNT(cid) = 0, выводится почему-то 1

Comment: замените * на любое поле из commtnts, например COUNT(c.pid)

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все как надо :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.pid,COUNT(*) FROM posts p LEFT OUTER JOIN comments c ON c.pid= p.pid GROUP BY p.pid
```