# Выборка sql Количество записей

Tags: mysql, join, выборка, sql

Как изменить запрос?

Нужно вывести из таблицы все записи + и сколько связей в другой таблице

COUNT (advert.sity)

нужно так

Домодедово (3)

Москва(2)

Киев(0)

```
sity
sity_ru              sity_in
--------------------------------
Домодедово     domodedovo
Москва              moskow
Киев                  kiev

adver 
--------------------------------
id         sity
1         domodedovo
2        moskow
```

Запрос

```
SELECT `sity`.`sity_ru`, COUNT(advert.sity) as num 
FROM sity INNER JOIN advert ON advert.sity = sity.sity_in 
GROUP BY sity
```

Выводит только если в таблице advert есть хоть совпадение 
Если совпадения нет то 0 не выводит

```
  Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [sity_ru] => Домодедово
                [num] => 3
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [sity_ru] => Москва
                [num] => 2
            )

    )
```

Comment: может так: 

    SELECT  `sity`.`sity_ru` , IFNULL( COUNT( advert.sity ) , 0 ) AS num
    FROM sity
    LEFT OUTER JOIN advert ON advert.sity = sity.sity_in
    GROUP BY sity

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте LEFT OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT `sity`.`sity_ru`, COUNT(advert.sity) as num 
FROM sity LEFT OUTER JOIN advert ON advert.sity = sity.sity_in 
GROUP BY sity
```

Кстати, такой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/299744/sql-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-count-0?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=299746#299746) уже был на форуме

Answer (score 0):

Для таблиц `city` и `advert` по `advert.city_id = city.ID`

```
SELECT      city.name AS Name,
            (   SELECT  COUNT(*) 
                FROM    advert
                WHERE   advert.city_id = city.ID ) AS Count
FROM        city
GROUP BY    city
```

Или

```
SELECT  city.name AS Name,
        COUNT(advert.city_id) AS Count
FROM    city
    LEFT JOIN advert ON 
        city.ID = advert.city_id
GROUP BY Name
```

UPD. Опоздал =)